# Can't get ID to close onclick

Tags: javascript, html, display

So the window's ID is moreInfo and the display is set to none in the CSS. The showMore function works to show the window, but when I click the close icon, the window is not disappearing.

HTML:

```
<div id="moreInfo">
            <div class="iconContainer">
                <img onclick = "javascript:close()" id="closeicon" src="images/closeicon.png"/>                
            </div>
            <div class="infoContent">
                <img id = "thumbnailimg" src = "images/charcoal.png" alt="image">
                <img id = "thumbnailimg" src = "images/charcoal.png" alt="image">
                <img id = "thumbnailimg" src = "images/stationary.png" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Page content -->
        <div class="imageSection" id="Charcoal">
            <h2>Soth Charcoal</h2>
            <div class="images">
                <img onclick="javascript:showMore()" id = "thumbnailimg" src = "images/charcoal.png" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>
```

javascript file:

```
function showMore(){
    document.getElementById("moreInfo").style.display= "block";
}

function close(){
    document.getElementById("moreInfo").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Hi Karen, Please change your function name `close` to some other name like `closeMore` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close is a reserved word. change the function name to myClose

```js
function showMore(){
console.log('show')
    document.getElementById("moreInfo").style.display= "block";
}

function myClose(){
   console.log('close');
    document.getElementById("moreInfo").style.display = "none";
    
}
```

```html
<div id="moreInfo">
            <div class="iconContainer">
                <img onclick = "javascript:myClose()" id="closeicon" src="images/closeicon.png"/>                
            </div>
            <div class="infoContent">
                <img id = "thumbnailimg" src = "images/charcoal.png" alt="image">
                <img id = "thumbnailimg" src = "images/charcoal.png" alt="image">
                <img id = "thumbnailimg" src = "images/stationary.png" alt="image">
            </div>
</div>

        <!-- Page content -->
        <div class="imageSection" id="Charcoal">
            <h2>Soth Charcoal</h2>
            <div class="images">
                <img onclick="javascript:showMore()" id = "thumbnailimg" src = "images/charcoal.png" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>
```